# Matplotlib's Basemap seems to not store map's center for later overplotting of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot the average daily temperature from the *NOAA Earth System Research Laboratory's Physical Sciences Division* onto a map created with `matplotlib`'s `Basemap`.

The dataset can be download as a netCDF-file from [here](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/fileServer/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface/air.sig995.2018.nc).

My problem is, however, that `Basemap` seems not to store the center (or boundary box) coordinates of the map as the subsequent overplot only fills part of the map, see the following figure:

[image: Map]

The code to generate the figure is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import netCDF4

# to check whether a file exists (before downloading it)
import os.path
import sys

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,6) )

temperature_fname = 'air.sig995.2016.nc'
url = 'https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/fileServer/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface/{0}'.format( temperature_fname)

if not os.path.isfile( temperature_fname ):
    print( "ERROR: you need to download the file {0}".format(url) )
    sys.exit(1)

# read netCDF4 dataset
tmprt_dSet = netCDF4.Dataset( temperature_fname )

# extract (copy) the relevant data
tmprt_vals = tmprt_dSet.variables['air'][:] - 273.15
tmprt_lat  = tmprt_dSet.variables['lat'][:]
tmprt_lon  = tmprt_dSet.variables['lon'][:]

# close dataset
tmprt_dSet.close()

# use the Miller projection
map1 = Basemap( projection='mill', resolution='l',
                lon_0=0., lat_0=0.
              )

# draw coastline, map-boundary
map1.drawcoastlines()
map1.drawmapboundary( fill_color='white' )

# draw grid 
map1.drawparallels( np.arange(-90.,90.,30.),  labels=[1,0,0,0] )
map1.drawmeridians( np.arange(-180.,180.,60.),labels=[0,0,0,1] )

# overplot temperature
## make the longitude and latitude grid projected onto map
tmprt_x, tmprt_y = map1(*np.meshgrid(tmprt_lon,tmprt_lat))
## make the contour plot
CS1 = map1.contourf( tmprt_x, tmprt_y, tmprt_vals[0,:,:], 
                     cmap=plt.cm.jet
                   )
cbar1 = map1.colorbar( CS1, location='right' )
cbar1.set_label( r'$T$ in $^\circ$C')

plt.show()
```

Note: if I set `lon_0=180` everything looks fine (it is just not the center position I would like to have)

I have the feeling that the solution is pretty obvious and I would appreciate any hint pointing me into that direction.

Comment: I suppose the data is aranged from 0 to 360 instead of -180 to 180. So you would need to move the second half of the data in front of the first half.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I somehow thought this would not be necessary, setting the boundary coordinates (or center coordinates) explicitly when creating the map

Comment: I think it *is* necessary. Compare to a simple line. It sure makes a difference whether it starts at 0 and goes to 360 or if it starts at -180 and goes to 180.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I guess I thought that after first creating the map with some boundary coordinates and *afterwards* calling the map routine to project the latitude/longitude coordinates of the data to be overplotted onto the map, those projected coordinates should fit onto the map (using the boundary conditions I explicitly set)

Comment: Try to convert lat-lon to x-y as `tmprt_x, tmprt_y = map1(tmprt_lon,tmprt_lat)`

Comment: @Serenity That would sure lead to an error because lon and lat are not necessarily the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers posted so far are a solution to my question (thank you, [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) and [swatchai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2177413/swatchai)).

I thought, however, that there must be a simpler way to do this (and by *simple* I mean some `Basemap` utility). So I looked again into the documentation [1] and found something which I overlooked so far: `mpl_toolkits.basemap.shiftgrid`. The following two lines need to be added to the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import shiftgrid
tmprt_vals, tmprt_lon = shiftgrid(180., tmprt_vals, tmprt_lon, start=False)
```

Note that the second line has to be added *before* the `meshgrid` call.

---

[1] https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html

Comment: Some typo: `tmprt_lons` -- > `tmprt_lon`. It works fine. Don't hesitate to accept your answer as the solution.

Comment: @swatchai thanks for spotting the typo (corrected now)

Answer (score 2):

As commented, the data is aranged from 0 to 360 instead of -180 to 180. So you would need to

- map the range between 180 and 360 degrees to -180 to 0.
- move the second half of the data in front of the first half, such that it is sorted ascendingly.

Adding the following piece of code in between your data extraction and the plotting function would do that.

```
# map lon values to -180..180 range
f = lambda x: ((x+180) % 360) - 180
tmprt_lon = f(tmprt_lon)
# rearange data
ind = np.argsort(tmprt_lon)
tmprt_lon = tmprt_lon[ind]
tmprt_vals = tmprt_vals[:, :, ind]
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import netCDF4

# read netCDF4 dataset
tmprt_dSet = netCDF4.Dataset('data/air.sig995.2018.nc')

# extract (copy) the relevant data
tmprt_vals = tmprt_dSet.variables['air'][:] - 273.15
tmprt_lat  = tmprt_dSet.variables['lat'][:]
tmprt_lon  = tmprt_dSet.variables['lon'][:]
# close dataset
tmprt_dSet.close()

###  Section added ################
# map lon values to -180..180 range
f = lambda x: ((x+180) % 360) - 180
tmprt_lon = f(tmprt_lon)
# rearange data
ind = np.argsort(tmprt_lon)
tmprt_lon = tmprt_lon[ind]
tmprt_vals = tmprt_vals[:, :, ind]

##################################


fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,6) )
# use the Miller projection
map1 = Basemap( projection='mill', resolution='l',
                lon_0=0., lat_0=0. )

# draw coastline, map-boundary
map1.drawcoastlines()
map1.drawmapboundary( fill_color='white' )

# draw grid 
map1.drawparallels( np.arange(-90.,90.,30.),  labels=[1,0,0,0] )
map1.drawmeridians( np.arange(-180.,180.,60.),labels=[0,0,0,1] )

# overplot temperature
## make the longitude and latitude grid projected onto map
tmprt_x, tmprt_y = map1(*np.meshgrid(tmprt_lon,tmprt_lat))

## make the contour plot
CS1 = map1.contourf( tmprt_x, tmprt_y, tmprt_vals[0,:,:], 
                     cmap=plt.cm.jet
                   )
cbar1 = map1.colorbar( CS1, location='right' )
cbar1.set_label( r'$T$ in $^\circ$C')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort, I guess this is the only way to do it. Meanwhile, I found the `Basemap` function `shiftdata` but so far it is not helping (I am currently playing around with it).

Answer (score 1):

This is challenging. I split the data array into 2 parts. The first part spans from 0° to 180°E longitude. The second part lying on the west side of 0° need longitude shift of 360°. Colormap must be normalized and applied to get common reference colors. Here is the working code and the resulting plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import netCDF4
import matplotlib as mpl

#import os.path
#import sys

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,6) )

temperature_fname =  r'.\air.sig995.2018.nc'

# read netCDF4 dataset
tmprt_dSet = netCDF4.Dataset( temperature_fname )

# extract (copy) the relevant data
shift_val = - 273.15
tmprt_vals = tmprt_dSet.variables['air'][:] + shift_val

tmprt_lat  = tmprt_dSet.variables['lat'][:]
tmprt_lon  = tmprt_dSet.variables['lon'][:]

# prep norm of the color map
color_shf = 40   # to get better lower range of colormap
normalize = mpl.colors.Normalize(tmprt_vals.data.min()+color_shf, \
                                 tmprt_vals.data.max())

# close dataset
#tmprt_dSet.close()

# use the Miller projection
map1 = Basemap( projection='mill', resolution='i', \
                lon_0=0., lat_0=0.)

# draw coastline, map-boundary
map1.drawcoastlines()
map1.drawmapboundary( fill_color='white' )

# draw grid 
map1.drawparallels( np.arange(-90.,90.,30.), labels=[1,0,0,0] )
map1.drawmeridians( np.arange(-180.,180.,60.), labels=[0,0,0,1] )

# overplot temperature
# split data into 2 parts at column 73 (longitude: +180)
# part1 (take location as is)
beg_col = 0
end_col = 73
grdx, grdy = np.meshgrid(tmprt_lon[beg_col:end_col], tmprt_lat[:])
tmprt_x, tmprt_y = map1(grdx, grdy)
CS1 = map1.contourf( tmprt_x, tmprt_y, tmprt_vals[0,:, beg_col:end_col], 
                     cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=normalize)

# part2 (longitude is shifted -360 degrees, but -359.5 looks better)
beg_col4 = 73
end_col4 = 144
grdx, grdy = np.meshgrid(tmprt_lon[beg_col4:end_col4]-359.5, tmprt_lat[:])
tmprt_x, tmprt_y = map1(grdx, grdy)
CS4 = map1.contourf( tmprt_x, tmprt_y, tmprt_vals[0,:, beg_col4:end_col4], 
                     cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=normalize)

# color bars CS1, CS4 are the same (normalized), plot one only
cbar1 = map1.colorbar( CS1, location='right' )
cbar1.set_label( r'$T$ in $^\circ$C')

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Seems very complicated to draw two different scatters. Instead, as I had already commented, you would just rearange the data. See my answer on how that could be done.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Well, not really if compare with the coding that arrange the data to -180 to 180.